# Can't remove keyboard shortcut for vertex paint

Tags: shortcut

I accidentally set a shortcut to vertex paint on left mouse button but not through user preferences and (after looking at countless answers here) never found a solution that works. I've been through user settings for what seems like hundreds of times now, and still can't get the problem fixed. Would it be worth reinstalling blender? I'm new, so I haven't made much progress yet.

I'm running Blender v2.79

Comment: Unless you saved new shortcut with Ctrl+U into the startup file it should be possible to get rid of it by saving the file, closing it, opening Blender and opening file from File > Open with Load UI unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can reset settings for Blender which is easier to do, you might want to preserve all the personal preferences. They will be all removed with *Load Factory Settings* and it should be used if other ways won't work.

The shortcut for toggling Vertex Paint interaction mode on Left Mouse was probably created by mistake from the changing modes menu in the 3D Viewport footer, when you misclicked on menu entry with <kbd>RMB</kbd> (which opened a context menu), then clicked on *New Shortcut* and next click was considered as input for the new shortcut.

To remove it open User Preferences > Input. Switch it to *Key-Binding* and enter "left mouse" as search word (without quotes).

[image]

Scroll the window down, to the *Object Non-Modal* section. There will be *Set Object Mode* setting with Vertex Paint as parameter and <kbd>LMB</kbd> as shortcut to invoke. Delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under "File" choose "Load Factory Settings".

Comment: Note that this will remove all saved settings including enabled addons, themes etc as well.